# How to get IE cookies that is in low folder

Tags: c++, api

IE stores some of it's cookies at `\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low`

I want to get these cookies, I use `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry,  FindNextUrlCacheEntryW` but it doesn't work for low cookies, it just work for the cookies that are in the low folder that are in cookies folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are "low cookies"?

Comment: the cookies that are in the low folder

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IEGetProtectedModeCookie? by any chance. That could solve some issues

Comment: You use FindFirstUrlCacheEntry() and FindNextUrlCacheEntry() to remove URLs and files from the Temporary Internet Files cache.

Comment: I now try it, but it doesn't help me

Comment: what should set for arguments